# Private method call exception for ActionView

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, testing

I have a functional test suite failing in a Rails 2.2.2 application. The exception thrown, and the associated lines are below:

> ActionView::TemplateError: Attempt to call private method
>
> On line #55 of app/views/wine/view.html.erb

```
53:     <% for activity in @activities %>
54:     
55:     <% if activity.context == 'ItemComment' %>
56:     <%= render :partial => 'item_comments/comment', :object => ItemComment.find(activity.context_id) %>
57:     <% elsif activity.context == 'Review' %>
58:     <%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :object => Review.find(activity.context_id) %>
```

This code functions as expected in every other environment besides test; moreover `activity` is merely an instance of an ActiveRecord called Activity, and `context` is a varchar column within the `activities` table. I am *not* overloading the getter or setter for `context` in the model. It is about as vanilla as you can get.

I'm baffled — I have never seen this before, and all attempts to isolate the cause have proved futile, as have Google searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the method `context` is being overridden in the test environment. It may be something only used in testing (such as a mocking framework). Or the load order may be different under the tests causing a plugin or lib to be included after your model is loaded.

Have you tried renaming the `context` attribute to something else?

**Update**: Are you using Shoulda in testing? That would explain the problem. I believe this defines a `context` method on Object causing your Activity model to inherit this. ActiveRecord defines the column accessor methods lazily (through method missing) which never gets triggered because the method is already defined. I suggest renaming the attribute.

Alternatively you can define the context method manually.

```
# in activity.rb
def context
  read_attribute(:context)
end
```

Comment: Ryan Bates is finally here.. Great! Really looking forward to more answers from you. 
Thanks,
Swanand

Comment: great, great answer, and seems to be spot-on. i didn't even think to think that shoulda was causing it. i'll try defining context explicitly in the model. thanks!